# java swing frame excellent for resultset from database

Tags: java, swing, data-binding

sir,
    l want to display resultset in jframe.i get output last record in the database displayed.
Lam intrested to place next button,back button in the frame.when i was click in the back button previosly viewed record is displayed and vice-versa.i don't know it will be possible.plz help me

Comment: I suggest you start by googling around a bit about swing and database access from Java, then code something, then if you run into specific problems, come back and ask more specific questions. To me it looks like you are asking us to write your program.

Answer (score 1):

Just to get you started I googled something for you: 
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Database-SQL-JDBC/JavadatabaseandSwing.htm

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Like @fish tells you in comments, go googling for data display and swing. once you'll have done that, take a look at [Glazed Lists](http://publicobject.com/glazedlists/), i think it may be of some help.

PS : even if my english spelling is not that good (and especially for readers like me who are not that fluent), I think you should consider do some spell-checking before posting.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a school assignment. If it is Java, [NetBeans](http://www.netbeans.org) can generate the entire application for you.

1. Open NetBeans. File -> New Project -> Java -> Java Desktop Application.
2. Select 'Database Application'. Click Next. Select your database connection and the table. Select the fields you want to display. Next
3. Now select the details field. Finish
4. Now run the application

I hope you don't try to submit the code as your assignment, if this is really an assignment.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want the ability to page through a ResultSet, displaying only one record per page. Check out this question: [what is best way to paging big Resultset -Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994954/what-is-best-way-to-paging-big-resultset-java)